# Jssor scale height of slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jssor

Hello I'm trying to set dynamic width (100% of container) and static height(550px) of slider on PC. On mobile it should be responsive. There is my code:

```
<div class="col-md-6 right-col" id="sliders">
        <div id="slider0" style="position: relative; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 712px; height: 550px; overflow: hidden; ">
             <div u="slides" class="slides2" style="cursor: move; position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 712px; height: 550px; overflow: hidden;">
                <div data-id="0">
                    <img u="image"  src='<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/grey.gif' data-original="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/w1.jpg" />
                </div>
                <div data-id="1">
                    <img u="image"  src='<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/grey.gif' data-original="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/w2.jpg" />
                </div>
                <div data-id="2">
                    <img u="image"  src='<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/grey.gif' data-original="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/w3.jpg" />
                </div>
            </div>

            <span u="arrowleft" class="jssora13l" style="top: 123px; left: 0px;">
            </span>
            <!-- Arrow Right -->
            <span u="arrowright" class="jssora13r" style="top: 123px; right: 5px;">
            </span>
        </div>

    </div>
```

Here is what I've tried with scaleWidth and height but it didnt goes with 100% width..

```
function ScaleSlider() {
            var parentWidth = jssor_slider1.$Elmt.parentNode.clientWidth;
            console.log(parentWidth);
            if(parentWidth > 798){
                jssor_slider1.$ScaleWidth(Math.min(parentWidth, 954));
            }else if (parentWidth > 720 && parentWidth >= 797){
                jssor_slider1.$ScaleWidth(816);
                jssor_slider1.$ScaleHeight(550);
            }
            else
                window.setTimeout(ScaleSlider, 30);

        }
```

How can I make that my slider have always 100% width of container and static 550px of height on PC?

Answer (score 3):

Jssor slider always keeps aspect ratio while scale.
You can use either `$ScaleWidth` or `$ScaleHeight`.

```
    function ScaleSlider() {
        var parentWidth = jssor_slider1.$Elmt.parentNode.clientWidth;
        console.log(parentWidth);
        if(parentWidth) {
            if(parentWidth > 798){
                jssor_slider1.$ScaleWidth(Math.min(parentWidth, 954));
            }
            else if (parentWidth > 720 && parentWidth >= 797) {
                jssor_slider1.$ScaleWidth(816);
            }
            else {
                jssor_slider1.$ScaleWidth(parentWidth);
            }
        }
        else
            window.setTimeout(ScaleSlider, 30);

    }
```

Comment: Ye I know it but, when i want to have on PC 100% width of container(bootstrap col-md-6) and 550px height not more not less then on mobile it doesn't scales properly. Did you know where is the problem?

Comment: Please remove `jssor_slider1.$ScaleHeight(550);`

Comment: It doesn't help because when I remove it it scales horrible on mobile.

Comment: According to your logic, it doesn't scale when parentWidth is less than or equal to 720.

Comment: Ok, I have different question. I have multiple sliders with unique id on one page, how can I get id of current slider and function that is fired when user change slides, for each slider of course. I have my sliders in array:
`$('.slider-right').each(function(i){
                jssor_slider_right[i] = new $JssorSlider$("sliderr"+i, options1);
            });`

Comment: jssor_slider1.$On($JssorSlider$.$EVT_PARK, function(slideIndex, fromIndex) {} );

Answer (score 0):

```
function ScaleSlider() {
        var refSize = jssor_1_slider.$Elmt.parentNode.clientWidth;
        var refSize1 = jssor_1_slider.$Elmt.parentNode.clientHeight;
        if (refSize) {
            refSize = Math.min(refSize, 830);
            refSize1 = Math.min(refSize1, 617);
            jssor_1_slider.$ScaleWidth(refSize);
            jssor_1_slider.$ScaleHeight(refSize1);
        }
        else {
            window.setTimeout(ScaleSlider, 30);
        }
    }
```